# Why is MessagePort.postMessage crashing Firefox?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, postmessage

I submitted [a crash report to Firefox](https://crash-stats.mozilla.org/report/index/61e46a17-f7c5-480a-b296-eb2450201127), but I would also like to make sure that I did not write something wrong or forbidden by the spec.

In the snippet below:

- The main process creates a web worker
- The main process creates a `MessageChannel`
- The main process sends `port2` to the web worker
- The web worker acknowledges the reception of the port
- The main process sends a message on the channel to request actual work
- The web worker creates 1000 `ArrayBuffer`s and transfers them back

**As stated in the title, this code crashes Firefox for me pretty much every time**. I tried to send a different amount of buffers, and it seems like the watershed is at about ~170 buffers. Specifically, I had the impression that up to 171, Firefox does not crash, but between 171-174 things get weird (as in the window becomes unresponsive, of nothing comes back from the worker) and at 175 it always crashes.

**Is my code wrong or is this a Firefox bug/limitation?**

Chrome, Edge and Safari seem to be okay with the code.

```js
addEventListener("load", () => {
  const workerSrc = document.getElementById("worker-src").innerText;
  const src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([workerSrc], { type: "application/javascript" }));

  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerText = "Click me!";
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const worker = new Worker(src);
    const channel = new MessageChannel();

    channel.port1.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
      if (message.data.name === "messagePortResult") {
        channel.port1.postMessage({ name: "getBuffers" });
      } else if (message.data.name === "getBuffersResult") {
        console.log("This is what I got back from the worker: ", message.data.data);
      }
    });

    channel.port1.start();

    worker.postMessage({ name: "messagePort", port: channel.port2 }, [channel.port2]);
  });

  document.body.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```html
<script id="worker-src" type="x-js/x-worker">
  let port = null;

  addEventListener("message", (message) => {
    if (message.data.name === "messagePort") {
      port = message.data.port;

      port.addEventListener("message", () => {
        const buffers = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          buffers.push(new ArrayBuffer(1024));
        }

        port.postMessage({ name: "getBuffersResult", data: buffers }, buffers);
      });

      port.start();

      port.postMessage({ name: "messagePortResult" });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug, and you are not doing anything "against the specs" no, your code "should" work.

You did very well opening [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1679611), in my experience these get treated faster than just crash reports and indeed it's already fixed after three days.

By the way, I made a simpler repro which doesn't use a Worker:

```js
button.onclick = (evt) => {
  const { port1 } = new MessageChannel();
  const buffers = [];
  for( let i = 0; i<1000; i++ ) {
    buffers.push( new ArrayBuffer( 1024 ) );
  }
  port1.postMessage( buffers, buffers );
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Crash Firefox Tab</button>
```

---

That being said, it is probably possible for you to workaround this bug.

- **This bug only concerns MessageChannel's MessagePorts.** Maybe you could rewrite your code so that you keep using the Worker's MessagePorts instead:

```js
const worker_content = `
  const buffers = [];
  for( let i = 0; i<1000; i++ ) {
    buffers.push( new ArrayBuffer( 1024 ) );  
  }
  postMessage( { data: buffers }, buffers );
`;
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ worker_content ] ) );
worker = new Worker( worker_url );
worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
  console.log( "received", evt.data );
};
```

- **Transferring that many *ArrayBuffers* sounds a bit weird anyway.** I'm not sure why you need to do this, but one way around until *SharedArrayBuffers* come back to play is to transfer a single big *ArrayBuffer*, and create many ["sub-arrays"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) from it.
  This way you can keep working on these as if they were many small arrays, while there is actually still a single underlying *ArrayBuffer* and GC doesn't have to kick in when doing many IO between both envs.
  I didn't really check, but I'd assume this will be faster than transferring that many small buffers in any browser.

```js
const nb_of_buffers = 1000;
const size_of_buffers = 1024;
const { port1, port2 } = new MessageChannel();
{
  // in your main thread
  port1.onmessage = (evt) => {
    const big_arr = evt.data;
    const size_of_array = size_of_buffers / big_arr.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    const arrays = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < nb_of_buffers; i++) {
      const start = i * size_of_array;
      const end = start + size_of_array;
      arrays.push( big_arr.subarray( start, end ) );
    }
    console.log( "received %s arrays", arrays.length );
    console.log( "first array", arrays[ 0 ] );
    console.log( "last array", arrays[ arrays.length - 1 ] );
    console.log( "same buffer anyway?", arrays[ 0 ].buffer === arrays[ arrays.length - 1 ].buffer );
  };
}
{
  // in Worker
  const big_buffer = new ArrayBuffer( 1024 * 1000 );
  const big_arr = new Uint32Array( big_buffer );
  const size_of_array = size_of_buffers / big_arr.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
  const arrays = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < nb_of_buffers; i++) {
    const start = i * size_of_array;
    const end = start + size_of_array;
    const sub_array = big_arr.subarray( start, end );
    arrays.push( sub_array );
    sub_array.fill( i );
  }
  // transfer to main
  port2.postMessage( big_arr, [big_buffer] );
  console.log( "sub_arrays buffer got transferred?",
    arrays.every( arr => arr.buffer.byteLength === 0 )
  );
}
```

- **In case you *really* need that many *ArrayBuffers***, you could create copies in each thread and use a single big *ArrayBuffer* only for transferring, filling the smaller ones from that big *ArrayBuffer*. This means you'll constantly have the data stored thrice in memory, but no new data is ever created after, and GC doesn't have to kick in.

```js
const nb_of_buffers = 1000;
const size_of_buffers = 1024;
const { port1, port2 } = new MessageChannel();
{
  // in your main thread
  const buffers = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < nb_of_buffers; i++) {
    buffers.push( new ArrayBuffer( size_of_buffers ) );
  }
  port1.onmessage = (evt) => {
    const transfer_arr = new Uint32Array( evt.data );
    // update the values of each small arrays
    buffers.forEach( (buf, index) => {
      const size_of_arr = size_of_buffers / transfer_arr.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
      const start = index * size_of_arr;
      const end = start + size_of_arr;
      const sub_array = transfer_arr.subarray( start, end );
      new Uint32Array( buf ).set( sub_array );
    } );
    console.log( "first array", new Uint32Array( buffers[ 0 ] ) );
    console.log( "last array", new Uint32Array( buffers[ buffers.length - 1 ] ) );
  };
}
{
  // in Worker
  const buffers = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < nb_of_buffers; i++) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer( size_of_buffers );
    buffers.push( buf );
    new Uint32Array( buf ).fill( i );
  }
  // copy inside big_buffer
  const big_buffer = new ArrayBuffer( size_of_buffers * nb_of_buffers );
  const big_array = new Uint32Array( big_buffer );
  buffers.forEach( (buf, index) => {
    const small_array = new Uint32Array( buf );
    const size_of_arr = size_of_buffers / small_array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    const start = index * size_of_arr;
    big_array.set( small_array, start );
  } );
  // transfer to main
  port2.postMessage( big_buffer, [ big_buffer ] );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for the repro and all the suggestions! Thank you for reporting the bug, I should have mentioned in the thread that I ended up reporting it myself, I apologize for that (that's why your report was closed).

Comment: I think the single buffer option would be the best thing to do, but it's kinda difficult for us to adopt right now (but that is exactly how I prototyped my first "fix" for our use case). Also using Worker.postMessage is not something that we can easily do but I did notice that it does seem to be immune. Thanks again!